# boost python dll load failed when wrapping a library function

Tags: python, c++, boost

I am trying to use boost.python to wrap exisiting c++ code. I want to make it a seperate project. Hence I wrap the function with a library call as follows.

```
#include < iostream >
#include "stdafx.h"
#include < boost/python/module.hpp >
#include < boost/python/def.hpp >
#include "mylib/header1.hpp"
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include "umf/header2.hpp"
#include "umf/header3.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::python;
using namespace my_ns;


void init(const char* name) {
    cout << "Hiiii " << name << "\n";
    my_ns::initialize();
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libname) {
    def("init", init);
}
```

When i remove the line my_ns::initialize(), the wrapping works. But if i include it I get

**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**

What could I be doing wrong here?